# MySql Query to Change a lower case to upper case

Tags: mysql, sql, string

How to change all lower cases in a string to upper cases using MySql Query?

Comment: change the table data or the result of the select?

Comment: i want to change the table data..

Answer (score 75):

If you want to update:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = UPPER(my_column)
```

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at using [UPPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)

> Returns the string str with all characters changed to uppercase
>   according to the current character set mapping.

From the LINK

> UCASE() is a synonym for UPPER().

Have a look at this example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9706a/1/0)

[Here is an example of changing the table data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67b3b/1/0)

Answer (score 9):

Use upper() or UCASE()

Example:

```
SELECT UCASE(columnName) FROM `table_name` 
SELECT UPPER(columnName) FROM `table_name`
```

Updation

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = UPPER(field_name)
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = UCASE(field_name)
```

Comment: What is the difference between the both.

Comment: @ramkumar, have a look at my answer, *UCASE() is a synonym for UPPER().*

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`UPPER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) for this:

```
select upper(MyColumn) 
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 4):

For column updates on a table, it may depend on if your collation is **case insensitive**. If that is the case then try using **Binary comparison**:

```
update table_name
set column_name = BINARY UPPER(column_name)
```

Otherwise this should work,

```
update table_name
set column_name = UPPER(column_name)
```

If you are using **MYSQL Workbench** and have **safe updates** on then try:

```
update table_name
set column_name = BINARY UPPER(column_name)
WHERE  column_name = BINARY LOWER(column_name)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code for change uppercase your query SQL:

```
UPDATE penduduk SET dusun = UPPER(dusun);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phpMyAdmin goes to SQL then type

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `ColumnName`=UPPER(`ColumnName`)
```

Eg:

```
UPDATE`cars` SET `Model`=UPPER(`Model`)
```

then save it.

PS: If you are a learner, follow this TIP

Before you type the `tablename`, you need to type this sign **`** before and after, as well as when you type the column name.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE
TableName
SET
ColumnName = UPPER(ColumnName)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.